# Wait for iframe to load in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, dom, iframe, dom-events

I am opening an iframe in JavaScript:

```
righttop.location = "timesheet_notes.php";
```

and then want to pass information to it:

```
righttop.document.notesform.ID_client.value = Client;
```

Obviously though, that line isn't going to work until the page has fully loaded in the iframe, and that form element is there to be written to.

So, what is the best/most efficient way to address this? Some sort of timeout loop? Ideally I would really like to keep it all contained within this particular script, rather than having to add any extra stuff to the page that is being opened.

Answer (score 100, accepted):

First of all, I believe you are supposed to affect the `src` property of iframes, not `location`. Second of all, hook the iframe's `load` event to perform your changes:

```
var myIframe = document.getElementById('righttop');
myIframe.addEventListener("load", function() {
  this.contentWindow.document.notesform.ID_client.value = Client;
});
myIframe.src = 'timesheet_notes.php';
```

Again, this is all presuming you mean **i**frame, not framesets.

Comment: Is there any way to do this by attaching an event? Let's say that the iframe may have it's own onload handlers and I don't want to accidentally clobber them by reassigning the onload property.

Comment: @Eric: yes. Use a library like Mootools, Prototype 1.6 or jQuery. If you don't have one of those, use this: http://ejohn.org/blog/flexible-javascript-events/

Comment: Ah... Does that mean that  this onload function in the script that triggers the page load, might interfere with an onload function in the page that has been loaded? I guess as long as they are not both trying to write to/from the same element it will be alright?

Comment: @Bill: no, @Eric's question was about whether this answer will interfere with any `onload="..."` attribute set on the `<iframe>` element itself. The answer to that is yes, it will. However any `onload` handler set *within* the iframe document is not affected.

Comment: Weirdly enough I can get this to work as <iframe onload=""> but not with iframe.onload = function(){}.

Answer (score 7):

I guess you can pretty easily do this with jQuery... [jQuery Home](http://www.jquery.com)
Just hook the page to the jQuery `$ function ()`... e.g.

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
    $('iframe').load(function() { 
       // write your code here....
    });
});
```

Have a quick look at the file uploader example here:
[Using iframes for multiple file uploads...](http://sushantp.wordpress.com/2009/05/11/using-iframes-for-multiple-file-uploads-and-using-jquery-to-communicate-between-main-document-and-iframes/)

Comment: I didn't really want to get into jquery (haven't opened that door yet), I was hoping just to deal with it in a few elegant lines of javascript. But thanks anyway Rajesh!

Comment: not an issue.. thanks for posting as i got to learn a few tricks without using jquery :)

Comment: Not working for me

Answer (score 2):

iFrame could have dynamically loaded elements and the best option to work with them is to use recursion:

```
 $('iframe').ready(function() {
   var triggerMeAgainIfNeeded = function() {
      setTimeout(function() {
          var neededElm = $('.someElementThatLoadedAfterIframe');
           if (neededElm.length > 0) {
             // do your job
           } else {
             triggerMeAgainIfNeeded();
           }
       }, 10);
   }
});
```

Comment: If going for setTimeout(), I guess we don't need iframe .read() ie can do that right when document .read()

Comment: Yes, @NamGVU but if iframe is added dynamically after document ready event then we need to listen iframe

Answer (score 1):

Try this simple solution:

```js
const myIframe = document.querySelector('iframe[name="my-iframe"]');
const waitForMyIframeToReload = () => (new Promise(resolve => myIframe.addEventListener('load', () => resolve())));
myIframe.contentWindow.location.reload(true);
await waitForSdiIframeToReload();
console.log('I executed after the iframe loaded'));
```

```html
<html>
  <body style="height: 100%; width: 100%;">
    <iframe name="my-iframe" src="https://platform.twitter.com/widgets/tweet_button.html" style="height: 100%; width: 100%;"></iframe>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

try this one...

```
$('iframe').each(function() { 
    $(this).ready(function() {
        $('#result').html("ready");
    });
});
```

Comment: The Original Poster never mentioned jQuery and hasn't got the jQuery tag in the post. I'd suggest then they aren't looking for a jQuery answer.