# iframe load event using jquery

Tags: jquery, asp.net, iframe

I have created a dummy page and placed an iframe in it. This iframe is loaded with an external webpage which has textboxes for username and password. In the pageload I have set values in hidenfields for the username and password. I need to load the textboxes with the hiddenfield values once the site is loaded to the iframe. How can i do this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [waiting for an iframe to load before passing information to it](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1463581/waiting-for-an-iframe-to-load-before-passing-information-to-it)

Comment: Thanks I got the load event but I am not able to set value to the textbox in the page loaded inside the frame.

Comment: When you say external webpage, do you mean from a different domain? If so, you cannot access the contents of the frame in javascript because of the same origin policy: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/364952/jquery-javascript-accessing-contents-of-an-iframe